# Sorting ArrayLists in Android

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I am developing an app. I wish to sort the `ArrayList`. The problem that I am facing is that whenever I have a duplicate entry, the sorting fails and the app crashes.

The layout as of now is:

[image: not in sorted order]

whereas I wish to have the result in the following manner:

[image: sorted]

I have written the following piece of code to sort.

```
private void sortAlphaNumeric() {
        /* Take a temporary list to store the original list */

        /*
         * Remove any white spaces in the question number as it might
         * interfere in sorting
         */
        String[] trimmedArray = new String[m_quesNumber.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_quesNumber.size(); i++) {
            trimmedArray[i] = m_quesNumber.get(i).replace(" ", "");
        }
        m_quesNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < trimmedArray.length; i++) {
            m_quesNumber.add(trimmedArray[i]);
        }

        ArrayList<String> temp_quesNumber = new ArrayList<String>(
                m_quesNumber);


        /* Sort the original list */
        Collections.sort(m_quesNumber, new AlphanumComparator());


        /* Temporary arrays */
        String[] temp_prevQuesId = new String[m_quesId.size()];
        String[] temp_quesMaxMarks = new String[m_quesMaxScore.size()];
        Integer[] temp_quesOptional = new Integer[m_quesOptional.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_quesNumber.size(); i++) {
            int old_position = temp_quesNumber.indexOf(m_quesNumber.get(i));

            temp_prevQuesId[i] = m_quesId.get(old_position);
            temp_quesMaxMarks[i] = m_quesMaxScore.get(old_position);
            temp_quesOptional[i] = m_quesOptional.get(old_position);
        }

        m_quesId = new ArrayList<String>();
        m_quesMaxScore = new ArrayList<String>();
        m_quesOptional = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < temp_prevQuesId.length; i++) {
            m_quesId.add(temp_prevQuesId[i]);

            m_quesMaxScore.add(temp_quesMaxMarks[i]);
            m_quesOptional.add(temp_quesOptional[i]);
        }


    }
```

Comment: why not just put all the properties into one object and use a custom comparator to sort?

Answer (score 1):

Make a model class like...

```
class Result {
    String qNo;
    int marksScored;
    int maximumMarks;
    ...
}
```

and make arrayList of `Result` like

```
List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
```

add required data, and after you can sort it by given code.

```
Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<Result>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Result lhs, Result rhs) {
                return lhs.qNo.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.qNo);
            }
        });
```

Comment: qNo is a String type.

Comment: @lisa I have updated my answer. that will help you :)

Comment: I get it in unsorted order:(

Comment: My code:List<QuesMarksRow> items = new ArrayList<QuesMarksRow>();Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<QuesMarksRow>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(QuesMarksRow lhs, QuesMarksRow rhs) {
     return lhs.getQuestion().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getQuestion());
    }
   });

Comment: I am saving all the data in the "items" arraylist

Comment: it would work then, try to log all data prior to sort and after sort.

Comment: I am getting the result right when the question_no are different. But when I have the same question_no, the marks of the second qNo gets over-written by the first qNo

Answer (score 0):

Just use this instead of all your code.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data; //then initialize it

// and pass it here. Sort based on column 0
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> row1, ArrayList<String> row2) {
        return row1.get(0).compareTo(row2.get(0));
    }
});
```

Comment: @lisa did my answer help you?

Comment: I get the results now but the sorting is not happening based on the question number

Comment: My code now:ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> m_quesNumber = new ArrayList<>();

   ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> trimmedArray = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < m_quesNumber.size(); i++) {
    trimmedArray.add(m_quesNumber);
   }


   Collections.sort(m_quesNumber, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> row1, ArrayList<String> row2) {
     return row1.get(0).compareTo(row2.get(0));
    }
   });

Comment: Why did you create 3-dimensional array? To crate table like in your question you only need 2-dimensional